# Convert class = tensorflow_serving.apis.classification_pb2.ClassificationResponse to json

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I've got a flask app which is taking in a text document, performing some jiggery-pokery on the text with nltk before passing this out to a served tensorflow model.

I pass this to the model with

```
result = stub.Classify(req, 10.0)
```

and get back the error

```
'TypeError: Object of type ClassificationResponse is not JSON serializable'.
```

Printing out from the Flask app using

```
print(type(result_, file-sys.stderr)
```

gives me the full class of:

```
class = tensorflow_serving.apis.classification_pb2.ClassificationResponse
```

and printing result to screen seems to be pretty much exactly what I want if it were JSON:

```
result {
  classifications {
    classes {
      label: "A"
      score: 48.48733901977539
    }
    classes {
      label: "B"
      score: 12.251751899719238
    }
    classes {
      label: "C"
      score: 2.919949769973755
    }
  }
}
model_spec {
  name: "my_model"
  version {
    value: 5
      }
  signature_name: "serving_default"
}
```

How can I convert this to JSON if the object type of 'ClassificationResponse' is not compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a serialized protobuf, you can use `MessageToJson` from the protobuf python library

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

jsonObj = MessageToJson(tensorflow_serving.apis.classification_pb2.ClassificationResponse)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much nessuno, I couldn't find any documentation on this in tensorflow.serving so that's really helped me out.